# What Date Format Should I Send When Using Oracle.DataAcess

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, odp.net, ora-01858

Converting from usind Micorsofts Syste.Data.OracleClient to what I believe is called Oracles ODT (Oracle.DataAccess 10.2.0.100).  When I try and send a date I get this error "ORA-1858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected".  This code worked great using System.Data.OracleClient.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("I_FIRST_LOSS_EVENT_DATE", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = .LossEventsMessages(0).LossEventTime
```

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: ".LossEventsMessages(0).LossEventTime" is defined as Date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Table 3-10 in the [Oracle Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E15167_01/featTypes.htm), the data type of the `Value` property of the parameter should be `System.DateTime` (unless you're willing to use an ODP.NET-specific type, in which case it should be `OracleDate` or one of the `OracleTimeStamp` types, depending on your column/parameter type).

Comment: I switched to OracleDate but get this error when I exicute it.

ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: Are you certain that this newer problem you're running into is caused by this parameter? From the sound of this most recent error message, I suspect that you may have an issue with the `OracleCommand`'s `CommandText` property.